# Elliptic curve cryptography for encrypting audio

Tags: encryption, public-key, elliptic-curves, block-cipher, stream-cipher

I want to use ECC to encrypt audio.

Is ECC encryption a stream cipher or block cipher?
I'm encrypting one sample (1 byte) at a time and I want to use multi-layer encryption (multi-ECC) to increase complexity but this increases the run time.

Should I use parallel computing to decrease the run time? 
Is that the right solution?

What is your advice?

Answer (score 4):

ECC is a form of asymmetric cryptography and is usually used for things such as key exchange or message signing. For encrypting the actual audio data you should probably look into a symmetric encryption algorithm such as AES or Chacha20.

Comment: But can use ECC in encryption through sender do these  1) encoding(convert samples to points) sample to point on the curve and then 2) encrypt point and receiver  do 1) decoding (convert points to samples) 2)decryption

Comment: @KawtherEsaa That's similar to ElGamal. You should instead use ECIES style  crypto.